# Reusing proxy protocol header on ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I can [turn on Proxy Protocol on ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html).

But in my case, I want to reuse proxy protocol header on ELB. Is it possible?

I mean I send a request with proxy protocol header already set to ELB. And I want ELB to take this particular header and pass it further. Not to generate a new one (in which source/port will be different from original one).

Comment: Turn proxy protocol support back off, and put the ELB listener in TCP mode and that is exactly the behavior you should see... but you may want to explain why you would want this.  I'm having a hard time time thinking of a situation where this would be useful.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thank you. We have a layer of balancers out of amazon infrastructure where we set proxy protocol header. And we can't pass requests directly to elb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the `PROXY` "header" is not technically inaccurate, but is potentially somewhat misleading or ambiguous terminology.

It is a "header" in the sense that it arrives at the beginning of a connection, but it is not an HTTP request header, unlike the familiar `X-Forwarded-For`, which is of course an HTTP request header.

Elegant in its simplicity, Version 1 of this protocol injects a message at the beginning of a TCP connection:

```
PROXY TCP4 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.11 56324 443\r\n
```

The fields are protocol (TCP over IPv4), source-ip, destination-ip, source-port, destination-port, separated by exactly one space each.

When the `PROXY` protocol is used in a stack, it is mandatory.  A missing or malformed `PROXY` message at the beginning of a connection is an error condition.  The existence of a `PROXY` message carries with it a level of trust higher than that provided by `X-Forwarded-For`, which is passed-through with modification (later values appended to earlier values).  The `PROXY` protocol makes no official allowance for cascading multiple values.

If you need ELB to transport this value "inside," then it's critical that the ELB's ingress security group be restricted only to accept requests from trusted source addresses.

Once that is done, tl;dr:

**Configuring the ELB listener in TCP mode (not HTTP) and disabling proxy protocol on the ELB itself will allow the original, external `PROXY` message to be transported through to the systems behind the ELB.**

It isn't possible to pass this through with an ELB in HTTP mode, because ELB doesn't expect it on requests, and the back-end connection can be reused for requests by multiple front-end clients, which is not fundamentally compatible with the proxy protocol -- it is designed to identify an incoming connection's client machine's IP source address and port (not an HTTP request's source IP and port)... and, as mentioned, it's not an HTTP request header.

The idea behind the `PROXY` protocol is to identify the originating client through a stack of components that are not payload-aware.  So, in this case, ELB needs to follow that model.  (It is, of course, possible, for an intermediate component to strip-off, then re-inject, that `PROXY` message, though this would be somewhat pointless in many cases, and ELB doesn't handle this configuration.)

In TCP mode, the ELB becomes protocol agnostic, and there is a 1:1 relationship between front-side and back-side connections, so the message should come through and work as expected.

One possible caveat to be aware of may depend on how ELB handles packet payload in TCP mode.  The proxy protocol requires that the entire `PROXY` message be present in the first data packet.  (The protocol is even designed in a way to guarantee that the data will always fit in a single segment.)  If ELB ever fragments this, the destination will need to be tolerant.  This seems unlikely to be an issue, but do be mindful of the possibility, if the final destination intermittently considers incoming streams to be invalid.